# React navigation StackNavigator - allow scenes in card to expand beyond available space

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm rendering a `StackNavigator` *inside* a `ScrollView` alongside other components that remain constant during navigation.  However, when viewed on phones with small screens, what happens is that the `StackNavigator` component becomes small enough to fit on the screen, thus hiding some of my content, rather than allowing scrolling to occur.  My code looks like this (with extraneous details removed):

```
const Navigator = StackNavigator ({
    splash: { screen: Splash },
    prompt: { screen: Prompt }, 
    ...
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'splash',
    headerMode: "none",
    cardStyle: { 
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        flex: 1
    }
});

...

    render () {
       return (
           <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{... flex: 1 ...}}>
                <ScrollView
                    style={{... flex: 1 ...}} 
                    contentContainerStyle={{
                        flexGrow: 1, 
                        justifyContent: "space-around",
                        alignItems: "center"
                    }}>
                    [other items here]
                    <Navigator />
                </ScrollView>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
```

The `Splash` component is quite small - it just renders a single line of text - but when it's replaced by `Prompt` (which is larger) I expected the `Navigator` to expand in order to allow the `ScrollView` to scroll to see all the content in `Prompt`, but it doesn't do so - the content is cut off at the bottom of the screen and cannot be scrolled.

Looking at the heirarchy of components with `react-devtools` shows a bewildering array of different components being injected into the layout: `Navigator` expands in turn to:

- a `NavigationContainer`
- a `Navigator` (seemingly unrelated to my own object of that name)
- an "`Unknown`" object
- a `CardStackTransitioner`
- a `Transitioner`
- a `View` (and its embedded `RCTView`)
- a `CardStack`
- two more `View`s
- a pair of `Container`s, each of which contains:
- a `Card`
- an `AnimatedComponent`
- another `View`
- a `SceneView`
- and finally my components.

Naively, it looks as though I somehow need to apply a `flexGrow` style to all of those intermediate levels in order to get this to work, but I don't see any options for controlling the styles of most of them.  How can I get the StackNavigator to expand as required to enable scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackNavigator (or the other navigators provided by react-navigation) is not intended to be rendered inside of ScrollViews.

It is hard to say what your goal is, but StackNavigator should be the top-level component of your app, instead of being nested like in the code snippet you provided.

My recommendation would be to create screen components that show your content (and these screen components can include a ScrollView). Then put the screens to a StackNavigator and render the created StackNavigator.

Comment: My intent is to have an animated component that sits above the section of the screen used for navigation and remains there consistently (maintaining its animation state through transitions), scrolling with the navigation screens if they are too large to sit on screen together.  I don't think this is achievable the way you suggest, unfortunately.  Wondering if perhaps I need to use a `SwitchNavigator` and manage handling transitions myself...?

Comment: you can use StackNavigator and provide your custom Header component https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html#header
that component will sit above the content